# How to give a pandas/matplotlib bar graph custom colors

Tags: python, matplotlib, pandas

I just started using pandas/matplotlib as a replacement for Excel to generate stacked bar charts.  I am running into an issue

(1) there are only 5 colors in the default colormap, so if I have more than 5 categories then the colors repeat.  How can I specify more colors?  Ideally, a gradient with a start color and an end color, and a way to dynamically generate n colors in between?

(2) the colors are not very visually pleasing.  How do I specify a custom set of n colors?  Or, a gradient would also work.

An example which illustrates both of the above points is below:

```
  4 from matplotlib import pyplot
  5 from pandas import *
  6 import random
  7 
  8 x = [{i:random.randint(1,5)} for i in range(10)]
  9 df = DataFrame(x)
 10 
 11 df.plot(kind='bar', stacked=True)
```

And the output is this:

[image]

Answer (score 159, accepted):

You can specify the `color` option as a list directly to the `plot` function.

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from itertools import cycle, islice
import pandas, numpy as np  # I find np.random.randint to be better

# Make the data
x = [{i:np.random.randint(1,5)} for i in range(10)]
df = pandas.DataFrame(x)

# Make a list by cycling through the colors you care about
# to match the length of your data.
my_colors = list(islice(cycle(['b', 'r', 'g', 'y', 'k']), None, len(df)))

# Specify this list of colors as the `color` option to `plot`.
df.plot(kind='bar', stacked=True, color=my_colors)
```

To define your own custom list, you can do a few of the following, or just look up the Matplotlib techniques for defining a color item by its RGB values, etc. You can get as complicated as you want with this.

```
my_colors = ['g', 'b']*5 # <-- this concatenates the list to itself 5 times.
my_colors = [(0.5,0.4,0.5), (0.75, 0.75, 0.25)]*5 # <-- make two custom RGBs and repeat/alternate them over all the bar elements.
my_colors = [(x/10.0, x/20.0, 0.75) for x in range(len(df))] # <-- Quick gradient example along the Red/Green dimensions.
```

The last example yields the follow simple gradient of colors for me:

[image]

I didn't play with it long enough to figure out how to force the legend to pick up the defined colors, but I'm sure you can do it.

In general, though, a big piece of advice is to just use the functions from Matplotlib directly. Calling them from Pandas is OK, but I find you get better options and performance calling them straight from Matplotlib.

Comment: Minor bug: my_colors = [cycle(['b', 'r', 'g', 'y', 'k']).next() for i in range(len(df))]   will give  'b' every time in python 2.7. You should use list(islice(cycle(['b', 'r', 'g', 'y', 'k']), None, len(df))) instead.

Comment: Thanks, I probably wouldn't have caught that. Another option is to create the cycle first, then just call its `next` function inside the comprehension.

Comment: Yup. it = cycle(['b', 'r', 'g', 'y', 'k']); my_colors=[next(it) for i in xrange(len(df))] would cut it as well...

Comment: With pandas and matplotlib installed today, the code above generates nothing for me, although it runs.

Comment: @kakyo Are you running in the regular interpreter, IPython, or from the shell (or something else)? Depending on which type of environment you execute this code within, you might need to turn on interactive mode for matplotlib, or set `pylab.ion()` for interactive pylab.

Comment: `this concatenates the list to itself 5 times.`  It already cycles through the list you give it; you don't need to do it manually

Comment: @endolith Yeah those are just quick examples. The part about concatenating the list to itself has zero bearing on this question or answer.

Comment: is there a way to set "color=my_colors" this in rcParams ?

Comment: If you're using seaborn, you can also have it generate a list of colors with the `sns.color_palette("Set2", 10)` for pandas/matplotlib to cycle thru, e.g. `df.plot.area(stacked=True, color=sns.color_palette('Set3', 12))`

Comment: @ely i am at `my_colors = [(i/30, i/20, 1) for i in df['values']]`, it does work... but the colors are way to similar...

Comment: Last gradient cmd yields a ValueError (out of range) `ValueError: RGBA values should be within 0-1 range` need to adjust it for other data

Answer (score 61):

I found the easiest way is to use the `colormap` parameter in `.plot()` with one of the preset color gradients:

```
df.plot(kind='bar', stacked=True, colormap='Paired')
```

[image]

You can find a large [list of preset colormaps here](http://scipy.github.io/old-wiki/pages/Cookbook/Matplotlib/Show_colormaps).

[image: colormaps]

Comment: in my case this only yields one color across all the bars

Comment: I found these colormaps lists useful https://matplotlib.org/examples/color/colormaps_reference.html
https://gallantlab.github.io/colormaps.html

Answer (score 21):

For a more detailed answer on creating your own colormaps, I highly suggest visiting [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18926031/how-to-extract-a-subset-of-a-colormap-as-a-new-colormap-in-matplotlib)

If that answer is too much work, you can quickly make your own list of colors and pass them to the `color` parameter. All the colormaps are in the `cm` matplotlib module. Let's get a list of 30 RGB (plus alpha) color values from the reversed inferno colormap. To do so, first get the colormap and then pass it a sequence of values between 0 and 1. Here, we use `np.linspace` to create 30 equally-spaced values between .4 and .8 that represent that portion of the colormap.

```
from matplotlib import cm
color = cm.inferno_r(np.linspace(.4, .8, 30))
color

array([[ 0.865006,  0.316822,  0.226055,  1.      ],
       [ 0.851384,  0.30226 ,  0.239636,  1.      ],
       [ 0.832299,  0.283913,  0.257383,  1.      ],
       [ 0.817341,  0.270954,  0.27039 ,  1.      ],
       [ 0.796607,  0.254728,  0.287264,  1.      ],
       [ 0.775059,  0.239667,  0.303526,  1.      ],
       [ 0.758422,  0.229097,  0.315266,  1.      ],
       [ 0.735683,  0.215906,  0.330245,  1.      ],
       .....
```

Then we can use this to plot, using the data from the original post:

```
import random
x = [{i: random.randint(1, 5)} for i in range(30)]
df = pd.DataFrame(x)
df.plot(kind='bar', stacked=True, color=color, legend=False, figsize=(12, 4))
```

[image]

Comment: Here's the documentation to other color maps apart from `inferno_r`: https://matplotlib.org/examples/color/colormaps_reference.html

Comment: I followed this snippet but my color array always has the same values.