# Multi colored bars based on category using matplotlib

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, matplotlib

I have created a chart based on three values in my 'result' field. Do you know how I can change the colors based on the three values (Abandoned, Connected, To voice mail) using the code I already have below:

```
data.direction.describe()
import seaborn as sns
%matplotlib inline
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
sns.set()  # use Seaborn styles

df = data.pivot_table('call_id', index='timeslot', columns='result', aggfunc='count')
ax = df.plot(kind='bar', width=0.7, align='center', stacked=False, rot=90, figsize=(12,6), legend=False, zorder=3)

plt.grid(zorder=0)
plt.legend(loc='upper center', bbox_to_anchor=(0.5, -0.3))
plt.xlabel("Timeslot")
plt.ylabel("Number of calls")
plt.title("Figure 4: Number of calls connected to the admin line by time slot")

ax.spines['bottom'].set_color('black')
ax.spines['top'].set_color('white') 
ax.spines['right'].set_color('white')
ax.spines['left'].set_color('black')

ax.yaxis.label.set_color('black')
ax.xaxis.label.set_color('black')

ax.title.set_color('black')

ax.patch.set_facecolor('white')

plt.savefig('figure4.png', dpi=300, facecolor=ax.get_facecolor(), transparent=True,  bbox_inches='tight', pad_inches=0.1)
plt.show()
```

This is how it currently looks but I want to be able to choose the colors. [Chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mNeqe.png)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pandas bar plot -- specify bar color by column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25689558/pandas-bar-plot-specify-bar-color-by-column)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using pandas, I'd suggest that you add your colors to the call to df.plot by using the color parameter.

```
ax = df.plot(color=my_colors, kind='bar', width=0.7,
```

Where 'my_colors' is a list of the colors you want to use.