# pandas dataframe binned data plotting

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe (df) with a column df.age ranging from 0 - 100 years and a column df.haircolor (bright, dark, purple, grey).

Now I want to bin the age in decades:

```
bins = np.linspace(df.age.min(), df.age.max(), 10)
decades = df.groupby(np.digitize(df.age, bins))
```

Now I am trying to find a good way to plot this. I'd like a barplot where each haircolor has a bar. Naively I tried that.

```
df['haircolor'].plot(kind='bar', by=decades)
```

It is not giving me the result I hoped for. Anyone an idea? thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
df['decade'] = df.age // 10 * 10
df.groupby(['decade', 'haircolor']).haircolor.count().plot(kind='bar')
```

Comment: That gives me a KeyError: 'decades'

Comment: Sorry, I thought you already had included the decade in your DataFrame.  See above for calculation.

Comment: Thanks Alexander, that works - do you know a way to colorcode the different haircolors too?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11927715/how-to-give-a-pandas-matplotlib-bar-graph-custom-colors