# How to plot pandas bar plot with sequential colormap?

Tags: python, pandas

There are many bar plot questions of similar question here in stackoverflow, but none of them completely answer the question.

I have a pandas dataframe and want to use pandas bar plot with increasing hue of given color (e.g. Blue, Red).

Here is my code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns

df = pd.DataFrame({'count': {0: 3372, 1: 68855, 2: 17948, 3: 708, 4: 9117}})

norm = plt.Normalize(0, df["count"].values.max())
colors = plt.cm.Blues(norm(df["count"].values))

df.plot(kind='bar', color=colors);
```

**Required**
Slightly blue color to lowest value.
Darkest blue color to maximum value.

Related questions:
[How to give a pandas/matplotlib bar graph custom colors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11927715/how-to-give-a-pandas-matplotlib-bar-graph-custom-colors/11927922)
[Change colours of Pandas bar chart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45967310/change-colours-of-pandas-bar-chart)

[image: light picture]

Answer (score 1):

Try changing the last line to `df['count'].plot.bar(color=colors)`

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is you are calling `.plot()` on `df`, which is a `pd.DataFrame`, and not on a `pd.Series`. Try this:

```
df['count'].plot(kind='bar', color=colors)
```

[image]